# using data.table in package development: Undefined global functions or variables

Tags: r, dplyr, package, data.table, r-package

The following code in a package I'm developing creates warning in R CMD check

```
Results[, errorMessage := as.character(errorMessage)]

no visible binding for global variable ‘errorMessage’
   Undefined global functions or variables:
     errorMessage
```

but `Results$errorMessage <- as.character(Results$errorMessage)` is fine

Does anyone know why this happens and how should I change the code with data.table to avoid the error?

Comment: Make sure that `DESCRIPTION` include `Imports: data.table` and `NAMESPACE` includes `imports(data.table)`, and last but not least that you include `.datatable.aware <- TRUE` somewhere in your package code (`./R/`). See https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-importing.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That it is a known issue, and likely documented (though I just failed to find it in the `FAQ` ...).  One of the magic powers of `data.table` is to not require quoted identifiers *within the scope of the object you use it with* (similar to R's own `with` and `within`) but that confused the parser checking for global symbols as it sees something unquoted ... and (wrongly) infers a global symbol.

We cannot fix that parser, but you can silence it. To do so, you can either rely on base R and put a

```
utils::globalVariables(c("errorMessage"))
```

in any of your R files, or just do

```
errorMessage <- NULL
```

somewhere to create a ('fake' as in unused) identifier.

Comment: Yes, good point, I missed that when I wrote my comment. It's an unfortunate state of dplyr- and data.table-based _package_ code that can be resolved with effort but doesn't need to always be the case. Having said that, this side of `R CMD check` has caught so many typos that I don't mind the noise ... and many of my packages have smatterings of `globalVariables`, somthing that seems sloppy but working.

Comment: Fully agreed! The test is good, the check for (inadvertent?) missing or misspelled variable is good -- as is the unquoted access in `data.table` and alike.  So I can live with the small tax of having to declare a global.

Comment: thanks a ton! Based on your answer I changed the code to `Results[, errorMessage = as.character(Results$errorMessage)]. Now the warning has gone
`

Comment: I am glad you got your error fixed but my preference would have been the simple `utils::globalVariables(c("errorMessage"))` to suppress the error -- while retaining the idiomatic `data.table` code.

Comment: @some, that code is not a valid `data.table` assignment operation, I get an error `unused argument`.

Comment: nice catch! it's a typo