# Why set variables whose names are data table's column names as NULL in a function?

Tags: r, data.table

Recently I'm working with some codes related to data.table in R. I just found when people wrote a function related to some data tables, they will first set the variables whose names are the data table's column names as NULL at the beginning of the function, for example:

```
round_vector = rep(x = 1:number_of_simulations, each = length_ints)
  round_vector = paste0('sim',round_vector)


  **s1 = s2 = unified_int = type_int = NULL**

  sample_dt = data.table::data.table(s1 = s1_vector, s2 = s2_vector, round = round_vector)

  uniq_sim_comb = unique(sample_dt[,.(s1,s2)])

  uniq_sim_comb[, unified_int := paste(sort(c(s1,s2)), collapse = '--'), by  = 1:nrow(uniq_sim_comb)]

  sample_dt[uniq_sim_comb, unified_int := unified_int, on = c(s1 = 's1', s2 = 's2')]

  sample_dt[, type_int := ifelse(s1 == s2, 'homo', 'hetero')]
```

This is a part of the code. This is a function using datatable, and unified_int, V1, and original... are column names of the data tables that will be used in the function. The author set the variables as NULL at first.

I thought this may be related to the data table's column behavior, but I cannot imagine in what circumstances, this would be a problem if I do not set the variables as NULL. I would be very grateful if anyone could share some insights!

Comment: One reason to do this would be to deal with “undefined global functions or variables” in a package. See https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-importing.html#globals or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242926/using-data-table-in-package-development-undefined-global-functions-or-variables

Comment: I'm not as fond of that technique, since it is _feasible_ that if expressions in that function attempt to use a column and the column does not rightfully exist, then the evaluation will find the same-named variable in the calling environment. For package development, I much prefer using `utils::globalVariables(c("s1", "s2", "unified_int", "type_int"))` (_outside_ of the function, somewhere in the global section of the file, always sourced when loading a package, never impacts _execution_ of the functions). One can have multiple such calls in different files in a package without problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that this is to ward off the `R CMD check` (or `devtools::check(..)`) warning about *"undefined global functions or variables"*, as @stefan identified. The notion from R's perspective is that there is a symbol being used in the function that has not been defined either as a formal argument or instantiated earlier in the function.

For instance,

```r
somefunc <- function(arg, vec, ...) {
  arg + vec
  L <- 42
  arg + L
  vec / div + L
}
```

In this case, `arg + vec` is fine because both are explicit named arguments to the function. `arg + L` is okay as well, because `arg` is a formal and `L` is previously defined. However, `div` is never defined *but is used*. This can be a mistake (e.g., typo, incomplete renaming of variables), but is more often (in new programmers) scope-breach, where they "know" that when the function is called, there is a variable named `L` in the calling (often global) environment. This breaks reproducibility, can be difficult to troubleshoot, and often leads to many bugs/problems. In CS in general, this is a bad thing and should be avoided.

**However**, packages such as `dplyr` and `data.table` allow us to work with expressions in a way that the R parser does not immediately recognize (i.e., NSE or non-standard evaluation). For instance, if you are familiar with each of these dialects (base, `dplyr`, and `data.table`), the following three expressions in another function are relatively equivalent but not equally recognized:

```r
anotherfunc <- function(x, ...) {
  x$var <- 99
  x <- transform(x, var1 = var + 2)
  x <- x %>% dplyr::mutate(var2 = var + 3)
  x <- data.table::as.data.table(x)[, var3 := var + 4]
  x
}
```

Running a check on the package containing this function:

```
── R CMD check results ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── somepackage 0.11.7 ────
❯ checking for missing documentation entries ... 
❯ checking Rd \usage sections ... 
❯ checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
   anotherfunc: no visible binding for global variable ‘var3’
```

(Note that `var1` and `var2` are recognized in their scope, but `var3` is not.)

To work around this, there are (at least) two techniques to mitigate the warning on R-check.

1. (***Preferred***) Use [`utils::globalVariables`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/globalVariables.html) to define what the developers *know* to be legitimate symbols but R does not recognize as such.

   ```r
   anotherfunc <- function(x, ...) {
     var3 <- NULL
     x$var <- 99
     x <- transform(x, var1 = var + 2)
     x <- x %>% dplyr::mutate(var2 = var + 3)
     x <- data.table::as.data.table(x)[, var3 := var + 4]
     x
   }
   utils::globalVariable(c("var1", "var2", "var3"))
   ```

   Here I've identified all three new variables as "known"; it's okay to add variables that are already correctly recognized or that are never used. This doesn't add anything to the function, it just suppresses warnings when found for specific symbols.

   My habit is to add `utils::globalVariables(..)` to every file with a reference that R does not recognize, its effects are additive. It is fine to have multiple uses of it throughout the files in a package, and it is not an error to have entries duplicated between such calls. I say this only to support my workflow: when I make changes to a file that affect what needs to be identified, I don't have to edit *another* file to remove those references. And by having all "this file's symbols" stored within "this file", if I remove a duplicated entry from another file (after editing its code and removing the particular symbols from the function), then this file will still safeguard the symbols used in this file's functions.

   Said differently: you may call `utils::globalVariables` as many times in a package as you want, without concern for repeated entries.
2. (***Discouraged***) Predefine dummy variables in the function:

   ```r
   anotherfunc <- function(x, ...) {
     var3 <- NULL
     x$var <- 99
     x <- transform(x, var1 = var + 2)
     x <- x %>% dplyr::mutate(var2 = var + 3)
     x <- data.table::as.data.table(x)[, var3 := var + 4]
     x
   }
   ```

   The problem that I have with this is that while it is *generally* safe, let's say for a moment that the `var3` assignment is not guaranteed to run. If we later reference `var3`, then it should be an error, but since we defined it earlier in the function, instead of an error, R will find the locally defined `var3` and do something with it (which may be meaningful to the expression or not).

   ```r
   anotherfunc <- function(x, ...) {
     var3 <- NULL
     x$var <- 99
     x <- transform(x, var1 = var + 2)
     x <- x %>% dplyr::mutate(var2 = var + 3)
     if (runif(1) < 0.5) x <- data.table::as.data.table(x)[, var3 := var + 4]
     x <- x[var3 > 9,] # should be an error but is not
     x
   }
   ```

Comment: "The problem that I have with this is that while it is generally safe, let's say for a moment that the x3 assignment is not guaranteed to run".  An excellent answer, as always, but I think `x3` here should be `var3`.

Comment: THANKS so much for the detailed explanation! Very helpful and easy to understand. Truly appreciate